# If there are special characters = true else = false problem with enumerating special characters

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that let's the user type anything in the console and if it has any certain special characters specified in the code underneath, it will return "True". If it doesn't contain any special characters then it will return "False". It seems that I have a problem in the third line of code specifically where the special characters are enumerated
(stringCheck = re.compile('!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_')) and I can't quite understand why.

Here is the code:

```
import re
    def hasSpecialCharacters(s):

    stringCheck = re.compile('!"#$%&\'()*+,-./\:;<=>?@[]^_')

    if (stringCheck.search(s) == None):
        print("False")
    else:
        print("True")


    
    
def main():
    print("Écriver une phrase.")
    trueOrFalse = str(input("=> "))
     
    hasSpecialCharacters(trueOrFalse)




main()
```

Here is the long error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vauto\Dropbox\PC\Documents\ALGO CCNB\Travail 2 (Programme B).py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\vauto\Dropbox\PC\Documents\ALGO CCNB\Travail 2 (Programme B).py", line 18, in main
    hasSpecialCharacters(trueOrFalse)
  File "c:\Users\vauto\Dropbox\PC\Documents\ALGO CCNB\Travail 2 (Programme B).py", line 4, in hasSpecialCharacters
    stringCheck = re.compile('!"#$%&\'()*+,-./\:;<=>?@[]^_')
  File "C:\Users\vauto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 252, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\vauto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\vauto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\vauto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Users\vauto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "C:\Users\vauto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_parse.py", line 671, in _parse
    raise source.error("multiple repeat",
re.error: multiple repeat at position 10
```

Comment: I hope this doesn't come off as rude, but have you tried reading at all about how regular expressions work? Followed a tutorial or anything? They're not just a list of characters, they have their own syntax. You're not following it, which is why you're getting that error.

Comment: I've researched a bit but I'll go ahead and search some more, thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: Agree with @CrazyChucky on this one. Unless this is the one and only time that you will ever use regular expressions, an answer to your question just fixing your code won't teach you much. Take some time to learn how they work because once you know how to use them you will want to use them over and over.

Comment: You can test your regular expression on [this site](https://regexr.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mus type

```
stringCheck=re.compile('[!"\#\$\%&\'()*\+,-./\\:;<=>\?@\[\]\^_]')
```

Error is due to the use of special characters for regex, to match that specials characters you must set `\` before the character.